# How to use dplyr to iteratively calculate summary variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data containing ratings of roughly 350 items.  Each item was rated by 10 people, who each rated 3 of the 350 items. So my columns are the ratings for each item, of which each item has 20 ratings.  So the columns look like Q20_1 Q20_2 Q20_3...Q20_20, Q22_1, Q22_2,...etc.  Each participant is a row.  So it's a 1166x7000 matrix of data.  Each row only contains data for 60 columns (3 items) responses, as participants only rated 3 items.

I want to use DPLYR to create summary variables.  Something like the average of Q20_1, Q20_5, Q20_7, and Q20_13...and then to repeat that for all of the items.  Then I would like to be able to create an average of those variables.

I've tried to do this in SPSS.  The code is pretty simple.

```
COMPUTE O15_Y=(Q30_1 + Q30_2 + Q30_3 + Q30_4)/4.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE O15_C=(Q30_5 + Q30_6 + Q30_7 + Q30_8)/4.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE O15_F=(Q30_9 + Q30_10 + Q30_11 + Q30_12)/4.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE O15_PS=(Q30_13 + Q30_14 + Q30_15 + Q30_16)/4.
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE O15_A=(Q30_17 + Q30_18 + Q30_19 + Q30_20)/4.
EXECUTE.

...

COMPUTE OA_Y=(O1_Y + O2_Y + O3_Y + O4_Y + O5_Y + O6_Y + O7_Y + O8_Y + O9_Y + O10_Y + O11_Y + O12_Y 
    + O13_Y + O14_Y + O15_Y + O16_Y + O17_Y + O18_Y + O19_Y + O20_Y)/20.
EXECUTE.
```

The above code is how I create the summary variables for one of the items.  Then when I have all of them, I average them together to get an average of all of those ratings across a group of interest.  The problem is I have to recreate this code for each of the 350 items, which is very time consuming.

It seems that dplyr can do this more efficiently, but I'm not quite sure how.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Are there any resources you used to help bridge the gap between SPSS and R? SO is not intended be your translator between programming languages, but rather to help you in the learning process. Please attempt a solution in R and revise your answer!

Comment: Typically I clean my data in SPSS and analyze it in R.  I've been looking at various dplyr tutorials.  It seems like something like:
`code`metadata %>%
  group_by(XXX) %>%
  summarize(mean_size = mean(ZZZZ, na.rm = TRUE))


Where each Q20_ is the grouping variables and then i specify the item numbers in the summarize code.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you've got data that look something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

metadata <- tibble(Q1_1 = c(4,5,5), Q1_2 = c(2,4,7), Q1_3 = c(8,3,9),
                   Q2_1 = c(0,1,3), Q2_2 = c(2,7,4), Q2_3 = c(1,1,4))
metadata 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>    Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q2_1  Q2_2  Q2_3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     2     8     0     2     1
#> 2     5     4     3     1     7     1
#> 3     5     7     9     3     4     4
```

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to group by some "Q#_" and then summarize all the responses for that "Q#_" (correct me if I'm wrong). You could try this:

```
metadata %>%
  gather(Q, val)%>%
  group_by(Q) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(val), median = median(val), sd = sd(val))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   Q      mean median    sd
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Q1_1   4.67      5 0.577
#> 2 Q1_2   4.33      4 2.52 
#> 3 Q1_3   6.67      8 3.21 
#> 4 Q2_1   1.33      1 1.53 
#> 5 Q2_2   4.33      4 2.52 
#> 6 Q2_3   2         1 1.73
```

Using `gather` we take the data from wide to long, then we group by the variable you are interested in and summarize the responses. Here I just show mean, median, and standard deviation, but you get the picture.